# PHP : How to send e-mail to the user using cron job

Tags: php, email, cron

I am new in programming so I really need a guide for my project. I need to send an e-mail as a reminder to the user either few days before or on the same day as the user inputted in their reminder. I know I will need a cron job in order to sent the e-mail automatically but I want to know, if my coding is correct and what do i need to add in order to let the cron job know how to send the e-mail. I am lacking so much so I appreciate any help.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smart_expenses_management");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smart_expenses_management");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$current_date = date("Y-m-d");

$email = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");

$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");

if(isset($res))
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //create instance of phpmailer

    $mail -> isSMTP();
    $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail -> Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $mail -> Password = '*mypassword*';
    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail -> Port = 587;

    $mail -> setFrom('myemail@gmail.com');
    
     $mail -> addAddress($email);   
    

    $mail -> isHTML(true);

    $mail -> Subject = "Reminder!";
    $mail -> Body = "test";

    $mail -> Send();

}
```

Update:
I corrected the code and tried to run and i got this error message.
p/s : i already configure the Gmail and App password.

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: trim(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, mysqli_result given in C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:1080 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1080): trim(Object(mysqli_result)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1014): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addOrEnqueueAnAddress('to', Object(mysqli_result), '') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\send_email.php(37): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addAddress(Object(mysqli_result)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 1080

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smart_expenses_management");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$current_date = date("Y-m-d");

$email = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");

$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");

if(isset($res))
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //create instance of phpmailer

    $mail -> isSMTP();
    $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail -> Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $mail -> Password = '*mypassword*';
    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail -> Port = 587;

    $mail -> setFrom('myemail@gmail.com');
    
    $mail -> addAddress($email);   
    

    $mail -> isHTML(true);

    $mail -> Subject = "Reminder!";
    $mail -> Body = "test";

    $mail -> Send();

}
```

Comment: `I want to know, if my coding is correct`...well have you tested it?

Comment: You can just test it from the command line first, get it working, and then set up the cron. Cron just adds a schedule on which to run the script, it doesn't change what the script actually does or how it works

Comment: My main comments on your code would be 1) why are you connecting to the database twice? 2) why have you turned off error reporting? and 3) as you're trying to use Gmail for SMTP you'll need to configure an App Password in your Gmail account if you haven't already

Comment: I corrected all of the things that you mentioned and for the Gmail and App Password, i already configure it but im afraid it might be some kind of privacy so i didn't want to reveal it. Anyway, thank you for pointing out, I appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line returns a mysqli_result and not the email.

```
$email = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");
```

You need to [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) the result and get the value like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$email = $array['email'];
```

Furthermore I don't know why you use two querys that do almost the same. Remove this line:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");
```

And replace:

```
if(isset($res))
```

with:

```
if(isset($email) && $email)
```

#### UPDATE

If you want to send the notification to multiple recipients you need to get ALL email addresses and add them in a foreach like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smart_expenses_management");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Unable to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$current_date = date("Y-m-d");

$emails = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM reminder WHERE reminder_date = '$current_date'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emails[] = $row['email'];
}

if(count($emails) > 0)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //create instance of phpmailer

    $mail -> isSMTP();
    $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail -> Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $mail -> Password = '*mypassword*';
    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail -> Port = 587;

    $mail -> setFrom('myemail@gmail.com');
    
    foreach($emails as $email) {
        $mail -> addAddress($email);
    }

    $mail -> isHTML(true);

    $mail -> Subject = "Reminder!";
    $mail -> Body = "test";

    $mail -> Send();

}
```

Comment: Its work omg thank you so much. But the problem now is, it only sent to one gmail account and doesn't work to other gmail account eventhough they have the same current date.

Comment: @Anynomous See the updated code for sending to multiple recipients. Maybe think about using addBCC instead of addAddress so that the recipients don't see the other mail addresses. Also it would be great if you could accept the answer if it works ;-)

Comment: Mad respect to you, its work! Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it! Don't worry i already accepted the answer. Hope you have a good day ahead!